# Custom Routes and Ransack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ransack

I'm using a custom route for my model

```
resources :operatives, :controller => 'users' do
end
```

I have a search form in my users/index file which worked before I changed to the custom "operatives" route.

```
<% search_form_for @q do |f| %>
```

Which gives the error

```
undefined method `users_path'
```

If I try to fix this by adding a url to the form:

```
<% search_form_for @q, url: operatives_path do |f| %>
```

The page loads, but the form is now not displayed.

How should I configure my search form?

UPDATE - you can see the rake routes output at:

https://gist.github.com/asecondwill/34831004b191fa3ac52353ead47c5a64

Comment: Can you show us the 'rake routes' output?

Comment: @Thrasher - routes output gist linked

Answer (score 6, accepted):

according to [docs](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/ernie/ransack/Ransack%2FHelpers%2FFormHelper%3Asearch_form_for) try defining search form like this:

```
<%= search_form_for(@q, url: operatives_path , method: :get) do |f| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks @Rcordoval Ill give you the tick  - i copy pasted your code to double check mine.  it was the missing **=** that was the issue.  doh doh doh DOH. : )